# jQuery crashing IE 9

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-9

I stripped down the code as much as possible to reproduce the error and put it on jsfiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/MwS8K/1/

Clicking the second tickbox twice crashes IE9. Also crashes IE9 mobile on Windows phone.

This has been reported to Microsoft and confirmed as a bug (but not a security risk). So, now looking for a different solution to this. Basically looking to hide/show table rows when a tickbox is clicked with jQuery.

```
<input checked="checked" class="Category1" id="Category1"  type="checkbox"       value="true" />
<label for="Category1">
    Category 1</label>
<br />
<input checked="checked" class="Category2" id="Category2" type="checkbox" value="true" />
<label for="Category2">
Category 2</label>
<br />
<div class="product-table">
<table border="0" id="ProductTable">
    <tr>
        <th>
            Product Name
        </th>
        <th>
            Action
        </th>
    </tr>
    <tr class="Category1">
        <td>
            Product1
        </td>
        <td class="call-to-action">
            View
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2">
             <hr />
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="Category2">
        <td>
            Product 2
        </td>
        <td class="call-to-action">
            View
        </td>
    </tr>
     <tr>
        <td colspan="2">
             <hr />
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

```
.product-table table td.call-to-action {
    border-top: 1px solid #DDD;
}

table { border-collapse: collapse; }


 $(document).ready(function () {
    $("input:checkbox").live("click", function () {
        if (this.checked) {
            var category = "#ProductTable tr." + $(this).attr("class");
            $(category).show('fast');

        } else {

            var category = "#ProductTable tr." + $(this).attr("class");
            $(category).hide('fast');
        }
    });
```

});

Comment: What exactly is the IE 9 bug? _"clicking checkbox twice"_?  Your example is using jQuery 1.6.4; does the jQuery version have anything to do with this?

Comment: Although jsfiddle and such are a nice *adjunct*, always post the relevant code/markup **in the question itself**. Why: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/118392/add-stack-overfow-faq-entry-or-similar-for-putting-code-in-the-question

Comment: What do you figure the odds are that to help you work around the bug, we have to *know what the bug is*? You say it's been reported and accepted; great, throw us a bone and give us the link or a description of it? Is it ticking the box? Showing/hiding the content? Does it relate to specific `id` or `name` or `class` values? Does it only happen on alternate Mondays? Sure, we can run the code and painstakingly repeat the work that's already been done to find the causal factor. Or you could, you know, tell us. :-)

Comment: go through to the jsfiddle link above, clicking the second tickbox twice in IE9 will crash. Like I said above

Comment: @Danny: You need to re-read the comments above.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on experimentation, the problem is using `hide` on a table row when there is a row following it with a `colspan`. Weird bug.

The solution is: Don't do that. It looks like in your specific case, the colspan is so you can put an `hr` between categories. This is probably better done with CSS anyway, e.g.:

```
.product-table tr.Category1 td, .product-table tr.Category2 td {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #DDD;
}
```

...and removing the unnecessary rows. [Like this.](http://jsfiddle.net/MwS8K/37/)

Comment: just to add, was about to post same thing, tho it took me a minute to find because you use horrible repetition of the word "category".  Try to break down you're identifiers a lil better

Comment: +1 just for "The solution is: Don't do that."  Reminds me of when Herman Cain said "The problem with that analysis is that it is incorrect."

Answer (score 0):

Besides the error it produces in IE9 you can drastically reduce the code used: http://jsfiddle.net/MwS8K/59/

update: and yeah it's recommendable not to use hr in a table, semantically incorrect anyways.

update 2: so then here is the code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(":checkbox").live("click", function () {
        $("#ProductTable tr." + $(this).attr('class')).toggle('fast');
    });
 });
```

Comment: For the same reason that code/markup should be in the question itself, not just in a link elsewhere, code/markup should always be **in the answer itself**, not just in a link elsewhere. See the link in the comment on the question for why.